# Search by category in jquery auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using category wise jquery autocomplete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories to show list in drop down. I pass city names as label and country name as category. search by label name works fine but I want to give option to search by country. If user type country name then all cities from the country should be shown in drop down list.

So if user type australia then I need to find all lebels with category australia and show them in drop down

I have attached image which shows current functionality

[image]

javascript code is

```
  $( "#loading" ).catcomplete
  ({

    source: function( request, response ) 
    {

        $.ajax({
              url: 'URL to fucntion',
              dataType: "json",
              data: {},
              async:true,
              success: function(data) {
                  var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) { 
                      return {
                          label: item.label,
                          category: item.category,

                      };
                  });
                  $("#loading").catcomplete({
                      source: cat_data,
                      minlength:0,
                      delay: 0

                  });
              }
          });

          },

        response: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.content.length) {                                        

            $( "#loading" ).catcomplete({
              source: [{"label":"australia","category":"sydney"},{"label":"australia","category":"melbourne"}]
            });


        } else {
            $("#message").empty();
        }
    } 

  });
```

Comment: Sounds like a tough problem.. What have you tried so far that didnt work? (I know your not just demanding that somebody write a solution for you without trying it first yourself)

Comment: I think you should do this in the server. The client doesn't take care about the filtering at all (in your case)

Comment: @mike510a  I tried like if user type something and if it is not matching to any city name but matching with country name then select country as label  and city as category. but this solution is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you include that code too? Maybe we can help you fix it.

Comment: I updated it in question used hard coded values for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I solved it using following code

use value and desc in json response instead of label and category

```
    $( "#loading" ).autocomplete({

        source: Json data here,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#loading" ).val( ui.item.label );
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#loading" ).val( ui.item.desc );
          $( "#loading-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
          $( "#loading-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );


          return false;
        }
      })
      .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) { 
        return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<div>"  + item.desc + "</div>" )
          .appendTo( ul );
      };
```